# Scrape table with div class by sibling, if data found

Tags: python, web-scraping

I would like to scrape a html table which contains elements in `<div class="...">` format. To scrape it I think I'll need to use:

```
if found driver.find_element_by_xpath contains(footable-row-detail-name)
get value from /following-sibling which is (class="footable-row-detail-value")
```

This is just one table. The site I'm scraping has a lot of tables and some tables don't have all the data (that's why "if found")

I would like to use python 3 for that.
I hope I explained it well. The HTML code for one table:

```
<div class="footable-row-detail-inner">
<div class="footable-row-detail-row">
    <div class="footable-row-detail-name">
        Discipline(s) thérapeutique(s):
    </div>
    <div class="footable-row-detail-value">
        197. Omeopatia, 202. Linfodrenaggio manuale, 205. Massaggio classico, 664. Riflessoterapia generale
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footable-row-detail-row">
    <div class="footable-row-detail-name">
        Cognome:
    </div>
    <div class="footable-row-detail-value">
        ABBONDANZIERI Katia
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footable-row-detail-row">
    <div class="footable-row-detail-name">
        Via:
    </div>
    <div class="footable-row-detail-value">
        Place du Cirque, 2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footable-row-detail-row">
    <div class="footable-row-detail-name">
        NPA:
    </div>
    <div class="footable-row-detail-value">
        1204
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footable-row-detail-row">
    <div class="footable-row-detail-name">
        Luogo:
    </div>
    <div class="footable-row-detail-value">
        Genève
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footable-row-detail-row">
    <div class="footable-row-detail-name">
        Tel / Cellulare:
    </div>
    <div class="footable-row-detail-value">
        022 328 23 44
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footable-row-detail-row">
    <div class="footable-row-detail-name">
        Cellulare:
    </div>
    <div class="footable-row-detail-value">
        079 601 92 75
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footable-row-detail-row">
    <div class="footable-row-detail-name">
        Discipline(s) thérapeutique(s):
    </div>
    <div class="footable-row-detail-value">
        <div class="thZone">
            <div class="zCat">
                METHODES DE MASSAGE
            </div>
            <div class="zThr">
                Linfodrenaggio manuale
            </div>
            <div class="zThr">
                Massaggio classico
            </div>
            <div class="zCat">
                METHODES PRESCRIPTIVES
            </div>
            <div class="zThr">
                Omeopatia
            </div>
            <div class="zCat">
                METHODES REFLEXES
            </div>
            <div class="zThr">
                Riflessoterapia generale
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Its hard to visualize the table you are trying to scrape without the css formatting. Can you provide the link to the website?

Comment: Thank you @fcsr This is the website: http://asca.ch/Partners.aspx?lang=it I'm clicking on Cantone - GE, clicking on the checkbox "Confermo di effettuare una ricerca a fine privato" and then Ricerca button

Comment: I am getting an actual html table structure. There are no divs with that class name. What library or method are you using to get the html code?

Comment: I used Inspector on Firefox, found the table and copied its outer html and posted here (beauty format done with selenium) Did you click on the drop-down menu selecting GE, the checkbox and button? It should show names which are expandable with arrows.

Comment: Can you try it on Chrome?

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch it? What should I do in chrome? Inspecting the page? I think the browser doesn't change anything.

Comment: Sorry then I can’t help. I can see the html table. Its loaded properly when I inspect the code. If you can see the html tables then with selenium and pandas you can scrape that in a few lines of code

Comment: Yes, I'm using Chrome. What's the code I should try to scrape the table?

Comment: Have you used selenium and chrome webdriver?

Comment: Yes, I did. I can move through the page, but I need the code to scrape the table. The one in my answer is not a code, it's an explanation. I'm using bs4, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This runs for me. I am using jupyter and running this line by line. You might encounter errors when the elements aren't loaded yet so please make adjustments if an error occurs for you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import pandas as pd


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://asca.ch/Partners.aspx?lang=it")

cantone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ddl_cantons_Input"]""")

cantone.click()

cantone.send_keys('GE')

cantone.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

confermo = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="MainContent__chkDisclaimer"]""")

confermo.click()

ricera = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="MainContent_btn_submit"]""")

ricera.click()

toggle = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("""footable-toggle""")
print(toggle)
while not toggle:
    time.sleep(.2)
    toggle = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("""footable-toggle""")

for r in toggle:
    time.sleep(.2)
    r.click()

data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("""footable-row-detail-cell""")

while not data:
    time.sleep(.2)
    data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("""footable-row-detail-cell""")

list_df = []
for r in data:
    ratum = r.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    datum = r.get_attribute('innerHTML')\
        .replace("""<div class="footable-row-detail-inner">""","<table>")\
        .replace("""<div class="footable-row-detail-row">""","<tr>")\
        .replace("""<div class="footable-row-detail-name">""","<td>")\
        .replace("""<div class="footable-row-detail-value">""","</td><td>")
    list_df.append(dict(pd.read_html(datum)[0].values.tolist()))

df = pd.DataFrame(list_df)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it. I have the code to go until expanding names to tables. I just don't know how to scrape them and build a nice csv table.

Comment: I tried the code with python 3. It opens the first page in Chrome and stops. In terminal there ae some data dispalyed 15 rows x 1 columns and that's all.

Comment: Are you sure its not 15 rows x 12 columns?

Comment: Yes, indeed, it shows it at the end of the terminal. But there are not the data I was trying to scrape. It's only "Altri luoghi di lavoro" and "e-mail". No name, phone numbers, address etc. I could try to change the code, but I don't understand how the "datum", "ratum" and ".replace" commands works.

Comment: I edited the code. I added `df.to_csv('data.csv')` this will save the data to data.csv. You will see it is complete

Comment: Thank you. This is what I'm having in terminal: [link](https://textuploader.com/1anyu)

Comment: Yes you will not be able to see all the data in the terminal since there is too much. Please check the csv for data completeness.

Comment: Thank you. The csv has the right data. I will mark it as solved. Just one more question: I'm trying to loop the code to all the pages, but after it goes to the next page it stops. This is the code: 'url = 'http://www.asca.ch/Partners.aspx?lang=it'
page = requests.get(url)
def click_next_page():
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MainContent_btnNextPackId"]').click()

print ('Completed Page: %s' %page)
try:
    click_next_page()
    page += 1
except:
    print ('No more pages.\nAll pages complete.')
    end = True

    time.sleep(3)'

Comment: You have to loop and run all the code to click each row again. Your loop must complete all the actions.

Comment: Can you please have a look at [this](https://textuploader.com/1anb5) I'm getting the data from the first page and then it goes through the rest of the pages without geting any data.

Answer (score 0):

One solution using python3 is [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) module!

There is a simple example to get you started :)